# GCC ARM SIMD intrinsics compiling to scalar instructions

Tags: gcc, arm, raspberry-pi3, simd, intrinsics

I have a music synthesis app that runs on a RPi3 (Cortex-A53) in 32-bit mode, under a Yocto-based RTLinux. I'm using GCC 6.3 to compile the code, which uses tons of SIMD intrinsics in C++ to operate on float32x4_t and int32x4_t data. The code is instrumented so that I can see how long it takes to execute certain sizeable chunks of SIMD. It worked well until a couple days ago, when all of a sudden after fiddling unrelated stuff it slowed down by a factor of more than two.

I went in and looked at the code that was being generated. In the past, the code looked beautiful, very efficient. Now, it's not even using SIMD in most places. I checked the compiler options. They include `-marm -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -O3`. Occasionally you see a q register in the generated code, so it knows they exist, but mostly it operates on s registers. Furthermore, it uses lots of code to move pieces of q8-q15 (a.k.a. d16-d31) into general registers and then back into s0-s31 registers to operate on them, and then moves them back, which is horribly inefficient. Does anyone know any reason why the compiler should suddenly start compiling the float32x4_t and int32x4_t vector intrinsics into individual scalar ops? Or any way to diagnose this by getting the compiler to cough up some information about what's going on inside?

Edit: I found that in some places I was doing direct arithmetic on int32x4_t and float32x4_t types, while in other places I was using the ARM intrinsic functions. In the latter case, I was getting SIMD instructions but in the former it was using scalars. When I rewrote the code using all intrinsics, the SIMD instructions reappeared, and the execution time dropped close to what it was before. But I noticed that if I wrote something like `x += y * z;` the compiler would use scalars but was smart enough to use four VFMA instructions, while if I wrote `x = vaddq_f32(x, vmulq_f32(y, z));` it would use VADDQ and VMULQ instructions. This explains why it isn't quite as fast as before when it was compiling arithmetic operators into SIMD.

So the question is now: Why was the compiler willing to compile direct arithmetic on int32x4_t and float32x4_t values into quad SIMD operations before, but not any more? Is there some obscure option that I didn't realize I had in there, and am now missing?

Comment: Can you show us a specific example of something that compiles nicely, and slightly different source that doesn't (with the same gcc version)?  e.g. in a small function that takes vector args and returns a vector, can you give an example of something that makes gcc do something sub-optimal?  Ideally you can link a code example on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ for ARM gcc 6.3 or one of the other ARM gcc versions it has.  gcc missed-optimization bugs and stupid stuff with vector vs. scalar does happen, but I don't think there's any general answer to this non-specific question.

Comment: Missing `-Ofast` (or `-ffast-math`). NEON floating point is non ieee754 conforming as it lacks denormals, so the compiler cannot use it unless explicitly directed to ignore correctness.

Comment: @EOF Yes! Somehow, I dropped `-ffast-math` in my fiddling. Thanks a million.

Comment: @EOF, make it an answer?